# vue: can v-html be inside a js array?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a js file containing array and objects. I need to style some properties from these arrays. For example

```
myArray= [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'honda',
    description: 'to buy the latest car, click here'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'tesla',
    description: 'to buy the latest car, click here'
  }
]
```

Let's say I want to style the `description` property so that I can bind a link there.
I figure that the way to do it is to use [raw html](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html). But in my case, I'm going to include it to my array. Is this possible? I have tried to search this question everywhere but there's no explanation for this case. Thank you so much.

Comment: sure, `description: '... <a href="#">...</a>...'`, then use `<span v-html="item.description"></span>`, make sure its not user supplied though, else XSS is possible. The only issue comes if you want to do vue in the string, ie a `@click="$router.push('/')"` etc, then your want to use the runtime complier

Comment: Your array values can contain HTML. In order to display it, you would need to use `v-html` as you already indicated, eg `<p v-for="obj in myArray" :key="obj.id" v-html="obj.description"></p>`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone ahh, I see! thank you so much for you answer!

Comment: @Phil thank you for your explanation! does this also work if not all `description` property are styled? I mean, for example, in another new object (another car), I don't want to add any v-html in the `description` property.

Comment: `v-html` doesn't require there to be HTML tags present. It will just output your `description` value as-is

Comment: @Phil It worked! thank you so much, I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any html styled code in your Array such as below.

```
myArray= [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'honda',
    description: '<a href="https://www.honda.com">to buy the latest car, click here</a>'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'tesla',
    description: '<a href="https://www.tesla.com" style="font-size:50px">to buy the latest car, click here</a>'
  }
]
```

And in your templete you would use: like

```
...
<div v-for="car in myArray" :key="car.id">
    <p v-html="car.description"></p>
</div>
```

[Check out this code.](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-wildflower-cfpho?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Check out this codepen.

You can check out the [vuejs documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML) for more info.